# How can you see the storyboard updated when you change the button views?

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, view

I change the corner Radius of my buttons programatically to

```
botton1.layer.cornerRadius = 5
botton2.layer.cornerRadius = 5
botton3.layer.cornerRadius = 5
botton4.layer.cornerRadius = 5
```

is there a way to see this change in the storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a great [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/90690/modern-core-graphics-with-swift-part-1).

Use `@ IBDesignable` just before the class declaration.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try [MengTo/Spring](https://github.com/MengTo/Spring) its great 3rd party pod that once you have installed, you can simply change the butte type in IB to **DesignableButton** and then you can set the corner radius in the **Attributes Inspector**. All of which will show up visually in your storyboard :D Oh it also has really easy animations in case you are interested